# Can I get a Mexican tourist visa in the UAE as a foreigner?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, mexico, uae, cameroonian-citizens

I am a citizen of Cameroon. I am currently in the United Arab Emirates (UAE) on a tourist visa. I would like to apply for a tourist visa to Mexico. Mexico does not have an embassy in my home country (Cameroon). Is it possible for me to apply for this visa at the [Mexican Embassy in the UAE](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/emiratosarabesunidos/index.php/es/)? If not, where can I apply for a visa?

Answer (score 11):

No you cannot. Most countries expect applicants to apply in countries in which they are nationals or long term residents.

[Embassy of Mexico in the Federal Republic of Nigeria](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/nigeria/index.php/en/welcome)

> Welcome to the website of the Embassy of Mexico in the Federal
>   Republic of Nigeria. Through this service, you can get updates on the
>   various documentation services, promotion and protection offered by
>   this representation, **with jurisdiction** in Angola, Benin, Burkina Faso,
>   **Cameroon**, Congo, Gabon, Guinea, Guinea Equatorial, Niger, Nigeria, Togo and the Economic Community of West African States (ECOWAS).

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot. From the [Mexican embassy in UAE's web page](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/emiratosarabesunidos/index.php/es/2016-05-07-05-34-59/2016-05-07-10-39-06):

> The applicant has to be resident in the United Arab Emirates

Visiting UAE for tourism would not fulfill the residence requirement.